# how can i read a midi file and get track's preset info in OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, core-audio, midi

I opened a midi file :

```
MusicSequence sequence;
NewMusicSequence(&sequence);
MusicSequenceFileLoad(sequence, (__bridge CFURLRef _Nonnull)(midiFile), kMusicSequenceFile_MIDIType, 0);
```

and read midi note message by using `MusicTrack` & `MusicEventIterator`.
how can i get the instrument preset info?such like `piano(id:0)` or someone else..

Comment: Those settings are made by events. And they are not necessarily presets; they can be changed at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Track's ***preset info***  or Instrument ***preset info*** are not concepts belonging to the MIDI standard, AFAIK. In order to find out if there is *program number set* or a *program number changed*, inside your MIDI read callback you should probably detect binary messages of type:

```
1100nnnn    0ppppppp
```

where `[nnnn = 0-15 (MIDI channel number 1-16)]`, and `[ppppppp = program number]`.

Yet these are just event generated program numbers which may refer to whichever sound. Original MIDI specification lacks a "sound-set-to-program-change-number" mapping, which is specified in General MIDI System. So, somewhere in your code there should be a search for GeneralMIDI system messages, such as:

General MIDI System ON (hexadecimal):

```
F0 7E <device-ID> 09 01 F7
```

General MIDI System OFF (hexadecimal):

```
F0 7E <device-ID> 09 02 F7
```

Full specifications can be read from: [MIDI Manufacturers Association](https://www.midi.org/).